# C++ “invalid comparator” error in operator overload when negating the result

Tags: c++

I ran into very strange problem regarding operator overload. The function below works fine outside the if branch. When I attempt to negate the result of comparison I always get “invalid comparator” error.
Negating using ! does not work, same with ternary operator. Why is this happening?

```
bool operator<(const Team& firstTeam, const Team& secondTeam)
{
 if (firstTeam.getId() > 8) {
  return !( firstTeam.getId() < secondTeam.getId());
 }
 return firstTeam.getId() < secondTeam.getId();
}
```

Comment: `if (firstTeam.getId() > 8 [enum constant]) {` That doesn't look like valid syntax to me. And what type are the IDs? Where is your MCVE?

Comment: Can you please give us the type of `Team::getId()` ?

Comment: [enum constant] it is only  for description 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there is team `a` with id 9 and team `b` with id 7, then `b < a` (outside of if) and `a < b` (inside if) are both true

Correct comparator should define [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering)

It's not 100% clear what are you trying to achieve, but the following code will define correct strict weak ordering

```
bool operator<(const Team& firstTeam, const Team& secondTeam)
{
 if (firstTeam.getId() > 8 && secondTeam.getId() > 8) {
  return firstTeam.getId() > secondTeam.getId(); // note > instead of <
 }
 return firstTeam.getId() < secondTeam.getId();
}
```